# Calculate Contact age in a Drupal view

Tags: drupal-views

I'm exposing civi contact data in a drupal view. I can expose date of birth, but not the contact age field.

Anyone know of a module/ combination of modules that will allow me to calculate age in years within the view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your view, pull in the CiviCRM birth date field.
Under date format, select Time ago.
This will present the D.O.B. field as 40 years 7 months

[image]

To remove years and months from the output you can ‘Rewrite results’ in the view and ‘Trim this field to a maximum length’ and set ‘Maximum length’ to 2 characters

Answer (score 1):

You need to add views php module

Add the dob into a view. In this example called birth_date

Add a global php field.

Then put this code into the output code box in the global php field

```
<?php 
$ageTime = $row->birth_date;
$t = time();
$age = $t-$ageTime;
$year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
$ageYears = $age / $year;
print floor($ageYears);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. 

Anil's suggestion has worked a charm. So I haven't needed to dabble with PHP